# What is "charAt(i) - 'a'" means in Trie structure?

Tags: java, data-structures

I am reading about the search function which checks the Trie data structure, but I don't understand why the code subtract the character a to get the index. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

```
// Returns true if key presents in trie, else false 
static boolean search(String key) 
{ 
    int level; 
    int length = key.length(); 
    int index; 
    TrieNode pCrawl = root; 

    for (level = 0; level < length; level++) 
    { 
        index = key.charAt(level) - 'a'; 

        if (pCrawl.children[index] == null) 
            return false; 
        pCrawl = pCrawl.children[index]; 
    } 
    return (pCrawl != null && pCrawl.isEndOfWord); 
}
```

Comment: This tutorial contains lots of explanations about TrieNode. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/

Comment: The code is from that website! I am sorry that I didnot mention in the text.

Comment: How can a `search` method on a trie ever be `static`? This sounds like a really bad tutorial. Also, a general-purpose trie must not assume that it gets only lowercase English letters, that's another sign for the bad code quality. Try to get a better tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java whenever we subtract a character from another character it converts both characters into ascii code and return their subtraction like:- ascii code of a is 97 & ascii code of b is 98 ( 'b' - 'a' ) will return 1

In your code when you will pass string in this method it will return subtraction of 'a' from each character of string

Comment: Java's text datatypes using the UTF-16 character encoding of the Unicode character set. A `char` is a UTF-16 code unit; a "character code" in generic terms.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `key` contains only lower case English letters, `key.charAt(i) = 'a'` maps each lower case letter to an index between 0 (for 'a') and 25 (for 'z').

The `children` array probably has a length of 26, and each element of that array corresponds with a latter between 'a' and 'z'.

Answer (score 1):

`char` variables are actually integral, reflecting the Unicode value of the corresponding char. `'a'` is thus in fact `97`; `'b'` is `98` etc. Subtracting 97 from a character will translate characters between `'a'` and `'z'` to numbers between `0` and `25`.